# Can I see from which Adwords ad a page visitor come from?

Tags: google-analytics, google-ads-api

I have just started use Google Analytics and Googe Adwords.

In my order pages (one per product) I can see how the visitor come to the site (which entry page, which key words etc.). But I have not managed to find out how to see from which Google Adwords ad a visitor come from.

I have activated Google Adwords for my site, but I want to find out which Adwords ads make the visitor to visit my order pages. And which Adwords ads make the visitor to just return immediately.

Anybody that knows what to do? Or where to find more information? :)

/Mia

Answer (score 2):

The best way to accomplish this is to [link Google AdWords to Google Analytics](http://support.google.com/adwords/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=1704341).  This will turn on autotagging which will then import click and cost data into Google Analytics for further analysis.  From here, you can analyze bounce rate and conversion rate by campaign, adgroup, and/or keyword.